# Migration issue with SQL-Server 'uniqueidentifier' column type into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

My client's old application is developed in .NET with MS-SQL database. The earlier developer used UNIQUEIDENTIFIER as the primary key for all tables that needed one.

In my new application that I'm developing using PHP & MySQL, I wrote the script to migrate all the data from MS-SQL to MySQL. The issue is with 2 tables particularly as below.

AccountMaster which has approx 45,000 accounts and Transactions which has approx 1M rows.

In the older application AccountMaster has ID as UNIQUEIDENTIFIER and Transactions table references it.

In my tables, I have migrated the AccountMaster ID as OldID and I'm creating new ID which are of type INT (Auto Increment).

So, I manage to migrate all 45K accounts in my AccountMaster as well as 1M transactions in my Transactions table while maintaining the old ID (UNIQUEINDENTIFIER) as OldID in both AccountMaster and Transactions.

Below is the scenario after migration in my MySQL database

```
AccountMaster
-------------
+----+--------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| ID | OldID                                | Name                  |
+----+--------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| 1  | 95221456-99BB-4B62-BA30-C8C527FD78E4 | Account 1             |
| 2  | 21952200-E0B9-434B-AAF7-D3EF96BCE16F | Account 2             |
| .  |                                      |                       |
+----+--------------------------------------+-----------------------+

Transactions
------------
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+---------+
| ID | OldAccountID                         | Date       | Amount  |
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+---------+
|    | 95221456-99BB-4B62-BA30-C8C527FD78E4 | 2018-10-07 | 100.00  |
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+---------+
```

The issue now is that when I run a query like below to update the Transactions table with the new IDs, it takes hours and never really completes. I have to abort it after 3 hours.

```
UPDATE `Transactions` AS A
    INNER JOIN `AccountMaster` AS B ON A.OldAccountID=B.OldID
SET A.ID=B.ID
```

Any idea how do I mitigate this issue? I'm pretty sure that the 36 character OldID is creating issues after migration even though all the columns 'ID' & 'OldID' in AccountMaster as well as 'ID' & 'OldAccountID' in Transactions in MySQL are indexed. The OldID and OldAccountID columns are of type VARCHAR(40).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, is the update statement order correct? In sql server it would be `update a set a.ID=B.ID from tran as a inner join acc as b on <join clause>` Secondly, I would always do the lookup in my initial write instead of having to do a second lookup. Thirdly, is the AccountId in the Transaction table just called ID, or is this the primary key  of the Transactions table? If its the AccountID then you should definitely rename it as this will confuse everyone. Apart from that what you are doing should work, but  as I said I'd avoid the update and write the new ID column up front.

Comment: @TomC The update command is in MySQL. When I execute it, there aren't any syntax errors. Also, when I execute a similar update statement on another pair of tables it works absolutely fine. Not sure what you mean by "I would always do the lookup in my initial write instead of having to do a second lookup"? Do you mean that I should perform the lookup and replacement during the initial migration itself? Wouldn't that be slow (I'd have to perform 1M lookups one for each transaction)? Thirdly, the column names provided here are to simplify my ques and not the actual names used in the application.

Comment: Re update on load - I would load the master table, create the index, then load the second table. But it does depend on how you are doing the initial load. Would never do a lookup on an un-indexed column so never 1M lookups per row, only ever 1 indexed lookup per transaction, same as you are doing now, but doing it once instead of one write for the load, plus an update (read+delete+write) for the update. If you cant do it directly in your load process, consider loading to a staging table, then doing the second write to live table including lookup.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely not try to update 1 million record in a single transaction.

I would split up the population based on the first couple characters of the old id. So, first update only those records where the first two characters of the old id is `'95'`, then go through all the possibilities. Before starting the update, I would do an analysis of how many records fall into each of the brackets. You do not want a bracket that has too many records.

Comment: In general an update of a million records should not be a problem for any database, but it does depend on available resources. This answer can definitely help if you are severely resource limited, plus it allows you a "progress bar" to give you visibility over whats actually happening.